# Recoding a variable based on a list or set of values?

Tags: spss

Is there syntax in SPSS that looks in a list or set of values?  I have been unable to find a syntax that will use a list/set as reference.

One use example is recode;

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
STRING V2 (A8).
RECODE V1 ('a' = 'group1') ('b' = 'group1') ('c' = 'group1') INTO V2.
EXECUTE.
```

Instead of typing each value like above, I would to use an function like  the SQL `IN`, if it exists.

Logic:

```
if V1 IN (a,b,c,e...) then V = "group1"...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some possibilities and examples to get you started:

Your `recode` command could be more compact, like this:

```
recode V1 ('a' 'b' 'c'='group1') ('d' 'e' 'f'='group2') INTO V2.
```

The `any` function gives you a logical value. For example:

```
if any(V1,'a', 'b', 'c') [do something]. /* can also use DO IF.
```

or

```
compute group1=any(V1,'a', 'b', 'c').
```

If you want to search for strings **within** values, you can use `char.index` this way (in this example the search string 'abc' is split into one character strings, so V1 is tested for containing each of 'a', 'b' and 'c' separately):

```
if char.index(V1,'abc',1)>0 V2='group1'.
```

for more complex options you can loop over values with `loop` or `do repeat`. For example, this loop will give V2 the value of 'grp1' for every value of V1 that contains 'a', 'b' or 'c', 'grp2' if V1 contains 'd', 'e' or 'f':

```
do repeat MyStr='a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f'/grp='grp1' 'grp1' 'grp1' 'grp2' 'grp2' 'grp2'.
   if char.index(V1,Mystr)>0 v2=grp.
end repeat.
```

Comment: Excellent, the any() is what was looking for! Your 'do repeat' example will be invaluable as well.

Comment: Another example if you have a very big list is to use a lookup table and then  use `MATCH FILES`.

Comment: @AndyW that's absolutely right for long lists - when you're looking for full mathces. Could also use when searching contained strings, but that would be more complex (I guess not through matching but use `write out` and `include` to create the syntax).